# Synonym for blindly, without worry

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a synonym for blindly and without worry, but without a negative connotation of a word like mindlessly.

> I would *blindly* hand my necklace to Tom to deliver. (without fearing he would steal it)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean *I [would **blithely** hand over](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22would+blithely+hand+over%22) my necklace*? Where *blithely* implies ***cheerfully, without any misgivings***. I'm not sure what "blindly" would imply, though (without "seeing, being aware of" a potential downside?).

Comment: Note that in such contexts, ***blithely*** often implies ***naively*** (which ***cheerfully*** normally doesn't).

Answer (score 17):

I see there is an accepted answer, but since the ask was for a single word, I also want to suggest:

> I would **freely** hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.

> I would **readily** hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.

> I would **gladly** hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.

all of which can mean willingly and without hesitation

Comment: readily seems like the best out of these options to convey what the original question asked for. To me, it has implications of a deep seated trust. "I would readily hand over my child to my best friend if I were to die"

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of options.

*I would **unhesitatingly** hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.*

***Without a second thought,** I would hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.*

***I wouldn't think twice about** handing my necklace to Tom to deliver.*

***I wouldn't hesitate** to hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.*

Answer (score 9):

Given the example sentence, the first word that came to my mind is **[blithely](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blithe)**.

> lacking due thought or consideration : casual, heedless blithe unconcern a blithe disregard for the rights of others

While 'blindly' doesn't fit perfectly (as 'blithely' implies lack of care while 'blindly' implies lack of ability), I would argue it could still fit if you were to consider it as doing something while blind to the consequences.

Comment: Exactly what I would have added, if noone had already suggested it.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're describing your trust in the receiver rather than an indifference to the necklace's well-being I would use this:

> I would ***confidently*** hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.

Comment: A very good one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider "insouciantly."  [Wiktionary offers this definition of "insouciant"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insouciant):

> Casually unconcerned; carefree, indifferent, nonchalant.
>
> [...]
>
> > 1913 August, L[ucy] M[aud] Montgomery, “The Christmas Harp”, in The Golden Road, Boston, Mass.: The Page Company, published April 1926, OCLC 150594789, pages 31–32:
> >
> > When we left the Marr house, he [Peter] had boldly said to Felicity, "May I see you home?" And Felicity, much to our amazement, had taken his arm and marched off with him. […] As for me, I was consumed by a secret and burning desire to ask the Story Girl if I might see her home; but I could not screw my courage to the sticking point. How I envied Peter his easy, insouciant manner!

Comment: To me, insouciant has a slightly negative connotation.

Comment: @barbecue Hm, well, I'd say the same about "blindly."

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

> I would ***unreservedly*** hand my necklace to Tom to deliver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Both ***unconcernedly*** and ***trustingly*** lack the negative connotations about the subject (that they're careless) that you wish to avoid.

Beyond that, ***trustingly*** has a positive connotation about the subject's view of Tom, while ***unconcernedly*** is neutral in that regard.  E.g., if you were willing to hand over your necklace to Tom because you didn't care whether he stole it or not, ***unconcernedly*** would work, while ***trustingly*** would not.

Indeed, ***unconcernedly*** is sometimes used to indicate a lack of interest rather than a lack of worry.  So some might interpret ***unconcernedly*** to mean the reason the subject is giving their necklack to Tom isn't because they trust Tom, but rather because they don't much care what happens to the necklack (unless you've established elsewhere that the necklack has value to them).

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact synonym, but if slightly informal language is acceptable, (it might be, because clearly this is a sentence someone is speaking aloud) you might emphasise your trust in Tom by saying something along the lines of

*I would hand over my necklace for Tom to deliver **any day***.

Answer (score -1):

Given the context: either ***Carelessly*** or ***Nonchalantly***

Carelessly: *in a casual or reckless way; inattentively.*

Nonchalantly: *in a casual way that shows a relaxed lack of concern or interest.*

Comment: Both of these words have significant connotations that were clearly not intended by the OP.